# Express parametric polymorphism and higher-order functions in UML class diagram

Tags: uml, higher-order-functions, parametric-polymorphism

Is it possible to express parametric polymorphism (generic types in C#) or higher-order functions in UML class diagrams?

If yes, how is this done?

If not, are there other diagram types more suitable to describe program architectures which include the listed features?

Background: I would like to describe an API which is written in Scala in a paper.

Answer (score 1):

Parametric polymorphism can be expressed by using UML Template take a look at http://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html